# Azure VM no response after installing update and auto-restart

Tags: azure, azure-vm

When there was an update being installed and it required a restart, Azure VM restarted during off-hours, then it went into no response state. I had to stop and start it via portal.

It occurred a couple of times already. One example is KB4592440.

=====

Windows Setup log:

9/12/2020 11:29:15 AM
A reboot is necessary before package KB4592440 can be changed to the Installed state.

System logs:

10/12/2020 1:18:00 AM
The process C:\windows\system32\svchost.exe (MyVM) has initiated the restart of computer MyVM on behalf of user NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM for the following reason: Operating System: Service pack (Planned)
Reason Code: 0x80020010
Shutdown Type: restart
Comment:

Other system logs:

The Windows Modules Installer service entered the running state.

The Update Orchestrator Service service entered the stopped state.

**The Update Orchestrator Service service terminated with the following error:
This operation returned because the timeout period expired.**

...(many other service went into stopped state)...

The Windows Event Log service entered the stopped state.

The Remote Desktop Services service entered the stopped state.

===========

No more logs. MyVM is stuck in nowhere, until I stopped & started it. Then there was a Setup log:

Package KB4592440 was successfully changed to the Installed state.

Appreciate any help.